# Group by before FROM clause is not working in prior version of Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a SQL which i wrote in Oracle 11g. But later on i found that Oracle 10.2.5.0 does not allow GROUP BY before FROM clause. I am not sure how to tackle this. I am not an expert in SQL though. Here is the SQL which is working in 11g.

```
SELECT F2.SCE_ID,
       (CASE
         WHEN TRIM(f2.process_step) IS NULL THEN
          f2.rtbl_element
         WHEN f2.process_step IS NOT NULL THEN
          f2.process_step
       END) AS rtbl_element,
       f2.version_num,
       f2.descr,
       f2.process_step,
       f2.rtbl_element_type,
       f2.predecessor,
       f2.RTBL_CHECKPOINT,
       f2.level_num,
       f2.level1,
       f2.LEVEL2,
       f2.LEVEL3,
       f2.LEVEL4,
       f2.LEVEL5,
       f2.LEVEL6,
       f2.LEVEL7,
       f2.LEVEL8,
       f2.LEVEL9
  FROM (SELECT f1.sce_id,
               f1.rtbl_element,
               f1.version_num,
               f1.descr,
               f1.process_step,
               f1.rtbl_element_type,
               f1.predecessor,
               f1.RTBL_CHECKPOINT,
               f1.level_num,
               SUM(gap) over(ORDER BY f1.rtbl_element) AS level1,
               f1.LEVEL2,
               f1.LEVEL3,
               f1.LEVEL4,
               f1.LEVEL5,
               f1.LEVEL6,
               f1.LEVEL7,
               f1.LEVEL8,
               f1.LEVEL9
          FROM (SELECT a2.sce_id,
                       a2.rtbl_element,
                       a2.version_num,
                       a2.descr,
                       a2.process_step,
                       a2.rtbl_element_type,
                       a2.predecessor,
                       a2.RTBL_CHECKPOINT,
                       a2.level_num,
                       (CASE
                         WHEN a2.rtbl_element = lag(a2.rtbl_element)
                          over(ORDER BY a2.rtbl_element) THEN
                          0
                         ELSE
                          1
                       END) AS gap,
                       a2.LEVEL2,
                       A2.LEVEL3,
                       A2.LEVEL4,
                       A2.LEVEL5,
                       A2.LEVEL6,
                       A2.LEVEL7,
                       A2.LEVEL8,
                       A2.LEVEL9
                  FROM (SELECT a1.sce_id,
                               a1.rtbl_element,
                               a1.version_num,
                               a1.descr,
                               a1.process_step,
                               a1.rtbl_element_type,
                               a1.predecessor,
                               a1.RTBL_CHECKPOINT,
                               a1.level_num,
                               (Row_number()
                                OVER(PARTITION BY a1.rtbl_element ORDER BY
                                     a1.rtbl_element)) AS level1,
                               a1.LEVEL2,
                               a1.LEVEL3,
                               a1.LEVEL4,
                               a1.LEVEL5,
                               a1.LEVEL6,
                               a1.LEVEL7,
                               a1.LEVEL8,
                               a1.LEVEL9
                          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a.sce_id,
                                                a.rtbl_element,
                                                a.version_num,
                                                a.descr,
                                                '' AS process_step,
                                                a.rtbl_element_type,
                                                (SELECT DISTINCT LISTAGG(b.predecessor,
                                                                         ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY predecessor)
                                                   FROM PS_RTBL_ELEM_PRED b
                                                  WHERE a.sce_id = b.sce_id
                                                    AND A.RTBL_ELEMENT =
                                                        B.RTBL_ELEMENT
                                                    AND A.VERSION_NUM =
                                                        B.VERSION_NUM
                                                  GROUP BY B.RTBL_ELEMENT) AS predecessor,
                                                (CASE
                                                  WHEN A.RTBL_CHECKPOINT <> 'Y' THEN
                                                   (SELECT DISTINCT CHK.RTBL_CHECKPOINT
                                                      FROM PS_RTBL_STEP_CHKPT CHK
                                                     WHERE CHK.SCE_ID = A.SCE_ID
                                                       AND A.SETID = CHK.SETID
                                                       AND A.RTBL_ELEMENT =
                                                           CHK.RTBL_ELEMENT
                                                       AND chk.RTBL_CHECKPOINT = 'Y')
                                                  WHEN A.RTBL_CHECKPOINT = 'Y' THEN
                                                   A.RTBL_CHECKPOINT
                                                END) AS RTBL_CHECKPOINT,
                                                1 AS level_num,
                                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.sce_id) AS LEVEL1,
                                                0 AS LEVEL2,
                                                0 AS LEVEL3,
                                                0 AS LEVEL4,
                                                0 AS LEVEL5,
                                                0 AS LEVEL6,
                                                0 AS LEVEL7,
                                                0 AS LEVEL8,
                                                0 AS LEVEL9
                                  FROM PS_RTBL_ELEMENT a
                                 WHERE A.EXCLUDE <> 'Y'
                                UNION
                                SELECT DISTINCT c.sce_id,
                                                c.rtbl_element,
                                                c.version_num,
                                                ' ' AS descr,
                                                c.process_step,
                                                ' ' AS RTBLTYPE,
                                                ' ' AS predecessor,
                                                c.RTBL_CHECKPOINT,
                                                2 AS level_num,
                                                0 AS LEVEL1,
                                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.rtbl_element ORDER BY c.rtbl_element) AS LEVEL2,
                                                0,
                                                0,
                                                0,
                                                0,
                                                0,
                                                0,
                                                0
                                  FROM PS_RTBL_STEP_CHKPT C
                                 WHERE C.RTBL_CHECKPOINT = 'Y') A1
                         ORDER BY a1.rtbl_element, A1.PROCESS_STEP) a2) f1) F2;
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be that the analytic function `LISTAGG` was introduced in 11.2.  The function call

```
LISTAGG(b.predecessor 
 ,',') WITHIN 
 GROUP ( 
 ORDER BY predecessor)
```

will not be valid in earlier versions.  Tim Hall has a rather canonical [list of string aggregation techniques in Oracle](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) that you can use to replace the `LISTAGG` function.  Personally, assuming that creating additional objects isn't an issue for you, I'd tend to use the custom analytic function approach.  If you really need the list that is returned to be sorted, you can use the [custom string aggregate function that sorts the elements](http://blog.sydoracle.com/2005/12/new-variant-on-stragg-ordered.html) that Gary Myers has written (or one of the other sorted string aggregate functions floating around).